# Require monotonic trend of variables by iterating over rows in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, trend

I want monotonic trend of a variables. Data looks like:

[image]

Output is required in the form of:

[image]

I have tried to iterate over rows using apply but got no luck. I have also tried is_monotonic_increasing and  is_monotonic_decreasing from pandas.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Picture are very poor medium to exchange data. It's bad for the environment and it mostly prevent other to help as they have to reinput data by hand. Always copy paste and format instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Series.is_monotonic_decreasing` can work for your case.

I would first `pivot` the dataframe in order to get each varaible in a column, then for each column drop `nan`s (otherwise `is_monotonic_decreasing` will always return `False`), apply both `is_monotonic_decreasing` and `is_monotonic_increasing` and collect the results:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "var_name": ["var1", "var1", "var1", "var1", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var3", "var3", "var3"],
        "Bins": [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2],
        "values": [162.5, 122, -15, -92, 40, 87, -37, 16, -69, 102, 17, 52, 109]
    })

df = df.pivot(index="Bins", values="values", columns="var_name")

result = {}
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dropna.is_monotonic_decreasing:
        result[col] = "Decreasing"
    elif df[col].dropna.is_monotonic_increasing:
        result[col] = "Increasing"
    else:
        result[col] = "No trend"
```

Comment: Thanks Matteo. It was really helpful.